# Open mdichild from another mdichild

Tags: c#

I have following forms : main_menu(mdicontainer), form1 and form2. I am able to open from1 in main_menu as mdichild by

```
form1 newMDIChild = new form1();

newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;

newMDIChild.Show();
```

When I try to open form2 as mdichild of main_menu from form1 by

```
form2 newMDIChild = new form2();

newMDIChild.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;

newMDIChild.Show;

this.close();
```

It still opening form2 as non-child form. I did not found any solution so far. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: How are you deducing that `It still opening form2 as non-child form`?

Comment: I'm not at a machine with vs installed so I can't test this but I'm pretty sure you can pass in the form into the `.Show(myform);`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx

Comment: Non-child form means that it just open form2 without bind to parent (to main_menu).      .Show(form2) does not work

Comment: Your code worked when I tried it.  Try posting more code that shows how you are doing this.

Comment: @LarsTech, exactly why I wondered how the OP determined it wasn't working. Thanks for the bump!

Comment: LarsTech, you are right. When I create new project, this code work. I did not try this code separately from rest of program. So thank you, I will try to find out problem elsewhere.

Comment: The problem was that I had `this.Close();` before `this.MdiParent;`. Thanks once again, solved.

Answer (score 0):

In your post you imply both forms are children of the same parent. If this is the case, form1's parent is being set to the correct parent, but form2's parent is being set to its parent's parent. In effect, it's making form2 a sibling to the object that is spawning it, rather than a child.

Try changing

```
newMDIChild.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
```

to

```
newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;
```

when spawning form 2.

Comment: I can not use `newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;` in form 1 because form1 is not MdiContainer